# how to display info for each unique item in mysql, combine info for each item

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, foreach

I am trying to loop through each unique item in a column in a mysql database

For example, the database is similar to below, I want to display the Model and Year for each unique color.

Example of database. (table is named "cars")

```
----------------------
Color | Model  | Year 
----------------------
Red   | Chevy  | 2014
----------------------
Blue  | Ford   | 2012
----------------------
Red   | Ford   | 2013 
----------------------
Red   | Ford   | 2014 
----------------------
Blue  | Ford   | 2012
----------------------
Blue  | Chevy  | 2012
----------------------
Red   | Ford   | 2011 
----------------------
Blue  | Chevy  | 2012
----------------------
```

I am looking for output like:
    Red
Chevy 1
Ford  4

Blue
Ford  2
Chevy 3

The code below will display each Color.

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if (!$con) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
mysqli_select_db($con,$dbname);

$sql="SELECT * FROM `cars`";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
echo "<br />" . $row['Color'] . "<br />";
}
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Below will count the distinct Colors.

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `Color`) from `cars`;
```

I need to run a function for each unique color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group by color and model as you fetch the results.

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $colors[$row['Color']][$row['Model']][] = $row['Year'];
}
```

Then output those groups with the counts for each color/model.

```
foreach ($colors as $color => $models) {
    echo "<h2>$color</h2>";
    foreach ($models as $model => $years) {
        echo "<p>$model: " . count($years) . "</p>";
    }
}
```

I added some basic markup for example, you probably already have an idea how you want to format the results, though.

Grouping like this also means you don't need to run a second query to count distinct colors.

```
$distinctColorCount = count($colors);
```

Comment: The number of square brackets does not seem to be correct in this line:  
    $colors[$row['color']][$row['model'][] = $row['year'];

Comment: Is capitalization important?  should I change some of these from $color to $Color?  Or, should I change the database table to use only lower-case for column names?

Comment: Yes, capitalization in the array keys must match the case in your column names exactly. (I edited the answer to reflect the case shown in your question.)

Comment: Thank you! Please let me know if there is anything else I should do. I'm not sure what the proper etiquette is for marking questions as answered and giving credit, etc.

Comment: You're welcome. There's not really anything else you can do. Accepting an answer with the checkmark indicates the answer that you think best solved your problem or answered your question, and as the question poster only you can accept an answer. You are not required to accept an answer if you don't think any of the given answers were sufficient, and you are free to change the accepted answer later. Voting up or down is something anyone can do and is just an indication of their opinion of whether the post was useful or not.

Comment: Well, I say anyone, I mean anyone with sufficient voting privileges. https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges The help center also has some guidelines on how to deal with answers as the question poster: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers